# compatibility mode server 2008 R2 higher than IE 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have 4 terminal servers, all running server 2008 R2, that need to run a few websites in compatibility mode. When I create the GPO, all I see is IE 7 compatibility mode... This works for all the sites except 1. When you run OWA in compatibility mode 7 you can't attach files to outgoing mail.

Is it possible to raise it from 7 to 9 within GPO?

Comment: hmmm, this might not be the case now, but I'm sure the options you are given for this are based on the version of IE installed on the server you are setting the gpo from. Is the server running ie8?

Comment: Yes, the domain controllers are running IE8. Only the terminal server has IE 11.

Answer (score 2):

If you want client-side granular control of the precise Internet Explorer version that a site is rendered in, upgrade to Internet Explorer 11 and configure the Enterprise Mode Site List.

Generally speaking, it is more effective to control this from the web server (using web.config).  If a web site was developed and tested against a specific version of Internet Explorer and does not render correctly in a higher version, the required version can be specified using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag.  If these are internal sites, it would be simpler to fix from the server side.

Specifying legacy document modes (at the web server)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Download Enterprise Mode Site List Manager
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42501

Turn on Enterprise Mode and use a site list
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx

[image: Enterprise Mode Site List Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade to IE11 yet in your enterprise you can edit iecompatdata.xml and push it by GPO. It's stored under %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\

- Dont forget to push the option to not download the compatibility's list from Microsoft web site, as it will overwrite that file

See there for detail; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622935(v=vs.85).aspx

See there for an example list for IE11; https://iecvlist.microsoft.com/IE11/1387494476607/iecompatviewlist.xml

IE10; http://iecvlist.microsoft.com/IE10/1152921505002013023/iecompatviewlist.xml

That create a list like that

```
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE8">dongbuhappy.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE8">frankfurter-sparkasse.de</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE8">garanti.com.tr</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE9" versionVector="9" uaString="9">keenelandselect.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE9" versionVector="9" uaString="9">khcu.ac.kr</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE10" versionVector="10" uaString="10" featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:false">webaam</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE10" versionVector="10" uaString="10" featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:false">webapps.easy2.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE10" versionVector="10" uaString="10" featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:false">workspace.gensler.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="EmulateIE10" versionVector="10" uaString="10" featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:false">xfinitytv.comcast.net</domain>
    <domain uaString="Chrome 28">loseit.com</domain>
    <domain uaString="Chrome 28">maktoob.yahoo.com</domain>
    <domain uaString="Chrome 28">vip.book.sina.com.cn</domain>
    <domain uaString="Firefox 22 Token">25moments.com</domain>
    <domain uaString="Firefox 22 Token">360safe.com</domain>
    <domain uaString="Firefox 22 Token">alexa.com</domain>
    <domain uaString="Firefox 22 Token">ansa.it</domain>
```